# Can I take night classes in Australia while on a working visa?

Tags: study

I was just wondering if I could take night classes while in Australia on a working visa. I’m currently studying welding and fabricating here, and also working in a welding shop, welding full time, with 2 years' experience; I was wondering, if I were to move to Australia on the working visa, would it be possible for me to continue my studies over there while I'm working?

Comment: What kind of working visa do you have? Please specify the visa subclass number.